# get JS to load on JQM page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile-pageshow

I am trying to get a plugin to run on JQM, but I need it to wait and load when page two is active. Right now, its loading when it starts up. I have my pages set up with `data-role='page'`. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#two").bind('pageinit')
    jQuery(".namesleft").fitText();
    jQuery(".scoreleft").fitText();
    jQuery(".namesright").fitText();
    jQuery(".scoreright").fitText();
});
```

thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/F2Gcm/

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){       
    $("h1").fitText(0.273);
    $(".download").fitText(1);
});
```

**On** method should be used instead of **live** method to bind a page event, **live** method is deprecated and don't exist in jQuery 1.9+.

Also this should be bound to **pageshow** event because it wont work in any other case. jQuery Mobile is strict with plugins doing visual changes, that kind of plugins will work only in **pageshow** event.

If you want a better understanding of jQuery Mobile page events take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery mobile has an alternative to `$(document).ready`.
The code should look something like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $('div:jqmData(role="page")').live('pagebeforeshow',function(){
             // code to execute on each page change
       });
</script>
```

In fact, jQm has an entire set of event alternatives to regular jQuery events:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: so your saying my code should look like this?
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $('div:jqmData(role="page")').live('pagebeforeshow',function(){
          jQuery(".namesleft").fitText();
          jQuery(".scoreleft").fitText();
          jQuery(".namesright").fitText();
          jQuery(".scoreright").fitText();
         });

Comment: Yes, and if you want this to only run on specific pages, you can change the selector.

Answer (score 0):

you can add your code in JQM's pageshow event like:

```
$("#two").live('pageshow', function(){
    $(".namesleft, .scoreleft, .namesright, .scoreright").fitText();
});
```

Comment: that makes the plugin not work at all not sure why but it does